# Scrapy to download specific type files

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm new to scrapy and python, I can able to download all the files but I want to download only specific Type files "EX-10", So that it will download followinh files. ( Ex-10.1, Ex-10.2 to EX-10.99).

My Code

```
import scrapy, os

class legco(scrapy.Spider):
name = "sec_gov"

start_urls = ["https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&SIC=2834&owner=exclude&match=&start=120&count=40&hidefilings=0"]

def parse(self, response):
    for link in response.xpath('//table[@summary="Results"]//td[@scope="row"]/a/@href').extract():
        absoluteLink = response.urljoin(link)
        yield scrapy.Request(url = absoluteLink, callback = self.parse_links)

def parse_links(self, response):
    for links in response.xpath('//table[@summary="Results"]//a[@id="documentsbutton"]/@href').extract():
        targetLink = response.urljoin(links)
        yield scrapy.Request(url = targetLink, callback = self.collecting_file_links)

def collecting_file_links(self, response):
    for links in response.xpath('//table[contains(@summary,"Document")]//td[@scope="row"]/a/@href').extract():
        if links.endswith(".htm") or links.endswith(".txt"):
            baseLink = response.urljoin(links)
            yield scrapy.Request(url = baseLink, callback = self.download_files)

def download_files(self, response):
    path = response.url.split('/')[-1]
    dirf = r"/home/surukam/scrapy/demo/tutorial/tutorial/Downloads3"
    if not os.path.exists(dirf):os.makedirs(dirf)
    os.chdir(dirf)
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
```

and Scrapy want to check for next pages also... (upto last page), Its not working Fine.

```
Rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@value="Next 40"]',)), callback="parse", follow= True),)

# follow next page links
    next_page = response.xpath('.//a[@value="Next 40"]/@href').extract()
    if next_page:
        next_href = next_page[0]
        next_page_url = 'https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?company=&match=&CIK=&filenum=&State=&Country=&SIC=2834&owner=exclude&Find=Find+Companies&action=getcompany' + next_href
        request = scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url)
        yield request
```

Comment: Do you have an example link where any of  these  Ex-10.1, Ex-10.2 to EX-10.99 are found? And do they still need the .html or .txt file mask?

Comment: Thanks for your responce Qharr, Check this [link](/home/surukam/scrapy/demo/tutorial/tutorial/moved_files) in this there more around 8 files is there. but I want only (EX-10.46, EX-10.47, 10.48).... same like this i want to check all files and download only this specif type filr EX-10 (so that it will download(Ex-10.1, EX-10.2 to EX-10.99). Ans It will be better If i get all the files in pdf format.

Comment: I get page not found 404 And by .txt and .htm I mean do you still want to filter on those in the format column?

Comment: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/914201/000089924302000881/0000899243-02-000881-index.htm

Comment: Yes for filter.

Comment: As a quick fix you can try replacing ***`start_urls`*** (the whole line) with ***`start_urls = ["https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&SIC=2834&owner=exclude&match=&start={}&count=40&hidefilings=0".format(page) for page in range(40,1440,40)] `*** to get the content from the next pages.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion SIM,  I'll try this..,

Comment: How can I use filter and download the specific type files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to have been solved. The following script should fetch you the required files from that site following every pagination links and downloading those files like the way you wanted to have.

```
import scrapy, os

class legco(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "sec_gov"

    start_urls = ["https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&SIC=2834&owner=exclude&match=&start=120&count=40&hidefilings=0"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.xpath('//table[@summary="Results"]//td[@scope="row"]/a/@href').extract():
            absoluteLink = response.urljoin(link)
            yield scrapy.Request(url = absoluteLink, callback = self.parse_links)

        nextpage = response.css("input[value='Next 40']::attr(onclick)")
        if nextpage:
            tpage = nextpage.extract_first().split("parent.location=")[1].replace("'","")
            nlink = response.urljoin(tpage)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=nlink, callback = self.parse)

    def parse_links(self, response):
        for links in response.xpath('//table[@summary="Results"]//a[@id="documentsbutton"]/@href').extract():
            targetLink = response.urljoin(links)
            yield scrapy.Request(url = targetLink, callback = self.collecting_file_links)

    def collecting_file_links(self, response):
        for links in response.xpath('//table[contains(@summary,"Document")]//tr[td[starts-with(., "EX-")]]/td/a[contains(@href, ".htm") or contains(@href, ".txt")]/@href').extract():
            baseLink = response.urljoin(links)
            yield scrapy.Request(url = baseLink, callback = self.download_files)

    def download_files(self, response):
        path = response.url.split('/')[-1]
        dirf = r"/home/surukam/scrapy/demo/tutorial/tutorial/Downloads3"
        if not os.path.exists(dirf):os.makedirs(dirf)
        os.chdir(dirf)
        with open(path, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer SIM, I can see that All EX files have been downloading, But I need only EX-10 (so that It will download EX-10.1, EX-10.2 to EX-10.99).., SO I have to add like this **for links in response.xpath('//table[contains(@summary,"Document")]//tr[td[starts-with(., "EX-10")]]/td/a[contains(@href, ".htm") or contains(@href, ".txt")]/@href').extract():**     AM I RITE ?

Comment: Yeah, it seems so.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `FilesPipeline`, but the one that scrapy provides generates the file name based on the hash of the URL.

If you want a custom file name, you have to make your own `FilesPipeline` like this:

```
import scrapy, os
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline

class legco(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "sec_gov"

    start_urls = ["https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&SIC=2834&owner=exclude&match=&start=120&count=40&hidefilings=0"]

    custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'myspider.MyFilesPipeline': 1},
        'FILES_STORE': '/my/valid/path/',
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.xpath('//table[@summary="Results"]//td[@scope="row"]/a/@href').extract():
            absoluteLink = response.urljoin(link)
            yield scrapy.Request(url = absoluteLink, callback = self.parse_links)

    def parse_links(self, response):
        for links in response.xpath('//table[@summary="Results"]//a[@id="documentsbutton"]/@href').extract():
            targetLink = response.urljoin(links)
            yield scrapy.Request(url = targetLink, callback = self.collecting_file_links)

    def collecting_file_links(self, response):
        for links in response.xpath('//table[contains(@summary,"Document")]//td[@scope="row"]/a/@href').extract():
            if links.endswith(".htm") or links.endswith(".txt"):
                yield {
                    'file_urls': [response.urljoin(links)]
                }

class MyFilesPipeline(FilesPipeline):

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        return request.url.split('/')[-1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Guillaume, I have some doubt, Where you have mentioned the fileTypes, I have to download some specify type files. Example (Ex-10)

Comment: You can  filter you the file names that you pass in the `file_urls` for example `if 'Ex-10' in links`: yield...`

Comment: you telling that, I want to add EX-10 in this line, EXAMPLE :  yield {
                    'file_urls': [response.urljoin(EX-10)]
                }. Am I rite ? or want to change something ?

Comment: Do you have an example URL of such file?

Comment: Yes, Check this link, [link](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/914201/000089924302000881/0000899243-02-000881-index.htm) In this there are a lot of files, but I have to download only EX-10.46, EX-10.47, EX-10.48.   same like each link have like this...

Comment: You can just change your xpath query to something like this: `'//table[contains(@summary,"Document")]//tr[starts-with(./td[4]/text(), "EX")]//td[@scope="row"]/a/@href'`

Comment: Sure, Let me try with this.